# Comparing files on two remote hosts using Ansible

Tags: linux, file, ansible

I am quite new to Ansible and am trying to wrap my head round some of the basic playbook functions. I have been searching around and can't seem to work out a way to take two files, both on separate servers and make a comparison between their contents. I need to be able to do this as I plan to automate some basic file management using Ansible/GIT.

Currently I am trying, but it doesn't seem to be working -

```
- name: get difference of two files
  command: diff test_user test_user
  hosts: me
  args:
    chdir: /home/vagrant/basicansible/tempcopy
  when: "diff.rc > 1"
  register: diff

- name: debug output
  debug: msg= "{{ diff.stdout }}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Its difficult to help when we don't know what the actual problem is :)

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten, I get and error that says 'args is not a legal parameter in an Ansible Playbook'

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46297528/edit) with any additional information as it can be missed by others if its in the comments. This is not my area of expertise - I was reviewing your question as all first posts go through a review process - but if you update your question, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I am interested in hearing what you are trying to achieve by running the diff command. Checking differences between files is something Ansible does well on its own when files are being copied between hosts. Try adding `--diff` to your playbook runs to output what Ansible is changing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you seem to be trying to achieve. Explanations below.

```
- hosts: me
  tasks:
  - name: get difference of two files
    command: >
      diff test_user1 test_user2
      chdir=/home/vagrant/basicansible/tempcopy
    register: difference
    failed_when: difference.rc > 1
    changed_when: difference.rc == 1

  - name: debug output
    debug: var=difference.stdout
```

There are a couple of problems with the playbook posted in the question:

1. "Hosts" is an argument to a play, not to a task
2. The arguments to diff as written in the question are the same file
3. The "when" argument applies to variables already set, as it handles if the task is to be run in the first place and thus cannot check the results of the task being run. Instead, you are looking to define what constitutes a change and a failure, see example above.

Comment: OPs syntax for `chdir` is perfectly ok (provided OP used the included code as a task, not a play) and complies to YAML. Yours uses Ansible-own invention which is generally lame.

Comment: If it is lame or not is a matter of preference; it has its uses. Thank you for the clarification though, that was my bad.