# How to compare two host config files in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, diff

I want to see if there is any difference between two files on the Remote Hosts.

**My task:**

```yaml
- name: compare files
  shell: diff -u -bB <(grep -vE '^@\s*(@#|$)' /tmp/{{myloopfile_list | basename }})  <(grep -vE '^@\s*(@#|$)' {{myloopfile_list}}) | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^-|+/ ) print $0;}'
  failed_when: "diff_output.rc > 1"
  register: diff_output
```

**Output:**

```json
...
        "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `diff -u -bB <(grep -vE '^@\\s*(@#|$)' /tmp/nginx.conf)  <(grep -vE '^@\\s*(@#|$)' /home/local/nginx.conf) | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^-|+/ ) print $0;}''",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('",
            "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `diff -u -bB <(grep -vE '^@\\s*(@#|$)' /tmp/nginx.conf)  <(grep -vE '^@\\s*(@#|$)' /home/local/nginx.conf) | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^-|+/ ) print $0;}''"
        ],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your RegEx has one too many `(` ( or one too few `)` ).

Comment: Where is `/tmp/{{myloopfile_list | basename }}` coming from? If you like to loop over `{{myloopfile_list}}` there are some information and configuration for the task necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you just want to compare 2 files, i suggest you to calcul and compare checksum:

```
  tasks:
    - command: sha256sum file1.txt file2.txt
      register: cksum
    
    - assert:
        that: cksum.stdout_lines[0].split('  ')[0] == cksum.stdout_lines[1].split('  ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to see if there is any difference between two files on the Remote Hosts.*

If you like to see what is actually the difference and based on your provided description, an approach can be

```yaml
- hosts: test.example.com
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Only show us what is the difference between
    shell:
      cmd: "diff -u -bB /tmp/{{ provided_config }} /home/{{ ansible_user }}/{{ actual_config }}"
    failed_when: difference.rc > 1
    changed_when: difference.rc == 1
    register: difference

  - name: Show difference
    debug:
      var: difference.stdout
```

**Further Reading and Similar Q&A**

- [How can I compare a remote file with a reference on controller without failing the playbook when different?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70844704/6771046)
- [How to get difference in two files using Ansible modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53822829/6771046)
- [Comparing files on two Remote Hosts using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46298709/6771046)
- [Ansible: Compare between two files on Remote Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56137741/6771046)